# Can't reach DemocracyConfig import

Tags: pallet, runtime, config, democracy

In the process of installing the democracy pallet in chain_spec.rs,
I am importing like this:

```
use pichiu_runtime::{ 
    constants::currency::PCHU, DemocracyConfig};
}
```

I cannot reach the imports and get the following errors:

```
 --> node/src/chain_spec.rs:8:29
  |
8 |     constants::currency::PCHU, DemocracyConfig};
  |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `DemocracyConfig` in the root

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `DemocracyConfig` in `pichiu_runtime`
   --> node/src/chain_spec.rs:280:30
    |
280 |         democracy: pichiu_runtime::DemocracyConfig::default(),
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `DemocracyConfig` in `pichiu_runtime`
```

I have tried to base myself off other parachains, polkadot and substrate code.

Comment: check if you have implemented it in your ./runtime/src/lib.rs like: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L888 and https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1595, so then you can import it into your ./node/src/chain_spec.rs like: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L25 and https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L325

Comment: I though that was what I was doing but following this exact receipe did the trick.
I was using:
democracy: Some(DemocracyConfig::default()) 
and 
Democracy: pallet_democracy::{Pallet, Call, Event<T>}
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not implemented **DemocracyConfig** in runtime.